# Change the color of TextView on different states

Tags: android, textview, android-studio-2.3

I want to change the color of TextView on different states for example on pressed, on focused etc.
I'm using the following code yet, and I need some addition which changes the color of TextView.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape>
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#FFFFFF" />
            <corners android:radius="2dp"/>
            <padding android:left="0dip" android:top="0dip" android:right="0dip" android:bottom="0dip" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <ripple
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:color="?android:attr/colorControlHighlight" android:state_pressed="true">
            <item
                android:id="@android:id/mask"
                android:drawable="@color/colorBackgroundDark"></item>
        </ripple>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using a drawable selector?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/background_category_filter_selected" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/background_category_filter_not_selected" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_pressed="false"></item>
</selector>
```

IN this example I have different drawables for when a button is pressed or not. There are other states you can use like active, focused...
Later I just do this

```
         <Button
                android:id="@+id/first_day_forward"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="36dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:background="@drawable/background_filter_button_square"
                android:text="&gt;"
                android:textAppearance="@style/fontMontseratReg"
                android:textColor="@drawable/filter_text_button" />
```

In the example I used a Button, but I reckon it works with Text View as well.

To change the fill in your xml **shape** tag use **solid**, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#ffffff"/>
    <corners android:radius="3dp"/>
</shape>
```

In you case you could do something like this:

```
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="false">
        <shape>
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#FFFFFF" />
            <corners android:radius="2dp"/>
            <padding android:left="0dip" android:top="0dip" android:right="0dip" android:bottom="0dip" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <ripple
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:color="?android:attr/colorControlHighlight" >
            <item
                android:id="@android:id/mask"
                android:drawable="@color/colorBackgroundDark"></item>
        </ripple>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've tried the selector, but it is not giving me any output.

Comment: I've shown my code, would you please tell me where I've to put selector ??

Comment: don't forget to mark as an answer so it can help others too :)